# Taylor Series for $ \ln {1\over (1-x)} $ about x=0

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Excuse me if I format things wrong; first time posting here. 
Anyway I am self studying Calc II again and I am just confused on the process of finding the taylor series for  $ \ln {1\over (1-x)} $.

My attempt:

I realize $ \ln {1\over (1-x)} $ is the same as $ \ -ln {(1-x)} $. This can then be rewritten as $ \ (-1) \int {1\over (1-x)}dx $. This resembles the geometric series, so we can rewrite it as $ \ (-1) \int \sum_{k=0}^\infty  {1\over (1-x)} dx $. We can then switch the position of the integral and sum to get $ \ (-1)  \sum_{i=0}^\infty\int  x^k dx $. Now here I brought back the $ -1 $ from the outside and reattched it to $ x^k $ so I then got, when integrating, $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {x^(k+1) \over (k+1)} $. This is just the series for $ ln(1+x) $ (minus the re-indexing) though. But they are two different functions and it's not the correct answer.

I don't care for the answer as I know what it is, I just want to know how to get there. Where did I mess up? And also, is the point of re-indexing when dealing with Taylor series to just get a better form that we can utilize?

TIA

Comment: It works just fine until you "reattach" the $-1$ to the $x^k$: $(-1) x^k \ne (-1)^k x^k$.

Answer (score 1):

You're steps appear correct but there is an erroneous negative sign thrown in there. You took the known power series for 
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+.....
$$
And integrated it term by term, which you can do within the radius of convergence of the geometric series and got
$$
\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx=\int (1+x+x^2+x^3+.....)dx\\
\Rightarrow -\ln(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+....=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}\\
\ln\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in this part, actually $-\ln(1-x)=\int\frac{1}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x$. Try to calculate the integral $\int\frac{1}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x$ carefully by doing subsitution $y=1-x$, and you'll find it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe differentiating is simpler. You have

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\ln \frac{1}{(1-x)}) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

Now you can just integrate the Taylor Series and get

$$\ln \frac{1}{(1-x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n} $$

Comment: @AOrtiz I politely disagree with you.